# How to get only the output values of list comprehension in python (not dtype)?

Tags: python

I have a list of values and for each of the values I would like to subtract a fixed value. When I do this with list comprehension the output is not a list, but a list that includes dtype in a messy way. I need just the values that are coming out of the list comprehension, which I want to put into a df later

The same problem occurs with map()

```py
>>> temp_times
[3.9629999999997403, 5.81899999999951, 8.31500000000233, 12.434000000001099, ...]

>>> temp_times = [x-start_program for x in temp_times]
>>> print(temp_times)
[64    3.775
dtype: float64, 64    5.631
dtype: float64, 64    8.127
dtype: float64, 64    12.246
...
```

Expected result:
[3.775, 5.631, 8.127, 12.246, ...]

Actual result:
[64    3.775
dtype: float64, 64    5.631
dtype: float64, 64    8.127

Comment: what's your `start_program` defined?

Comment: apparently not a float. Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your variable "start_program" is not a float. Try to convert it to float before subtraction.

Comment: Yes, thats it. It works now. start_program comes from another dataframe and even though in my output it says "float64", the actual datatype was a pandas Series. Thank you!